# How to format a date in a table, but only in a particular table

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI table that looks, in part, as follows:

[image]

I want to format the Import Date column such that the time portion doesn't display. However, I want to do this only for this table. I have this column in other places where I want it formatted a bit differently. I can't find a way to format this date just for this table, but no where else it's used.

Comment: The workaround is to create a new column and making adjustments for the new col: `ImportDate_thistable = ImportDate` then make format changes to `ImportDate_thistable`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you might want to add in another column that only indicated date, so that you can apply this column in your table.